# How to create 'n' child objects and parent at the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp.net mvc razor, and I'm making a view to create a parent's object, but along creating the parent I need to create 'n' child objects. How can I do this exactly?

I will reinforce that I'm not expecting to **display** the object's, I need to create them in one go, I say this only because I saw too many misunderstanding in my research.

Let me explain exactly what i need to do:

I have a model called **'Car'**, this model have a child element: **ICollection< Extra >**, when the user will insert a new **'Car'** he may be capable of **insert 'Extra' stuff before inserting the 'Car' to the database**. And the 'Extra' could have **N** elements, so it's not fixed.

My model as example:

```
    [Table("Car")]
    public partial class Car
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdCar { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Display(Name = "Car")]
        public string DsCar { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Extra> Extra{ get; set; }
}
```

Here's a view example of what i want to do that could help:
[Insert Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HymOs.png)

I wish to avoid the page refreshing effect if possible too.

Comment: Hi Emma, I inserted my model to make the example a little better, but there's no much to show as I'm still searching for the proper way to build it.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying for, why not just use a List<Extra> ??

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a single view where i can create both parent and multiple child objects, actually transforming my collection on a list is not a problem, i just left the way my data migrations created for me.

Comment: The way I like to handle scenarios like this is using javascript for adding removing child collections. You can create a javascript object in the same definition like your db entity "Car". And use javascript array for the "Extra" collection. In your user interface add and edit the array as you wish. Then you can postback the javascript "Car" object as JSON string to the server with a hidden field. Then read the hidden field value in your MVC controller and deserialize it into a C# "Car" object.

Comment: @TSungur should I control this in a partial view? That sort of issue should appear very often in this project, and I think following this structure can leave the project kinda messy, am i wrong?

Comment: @ValdirMarcheuskiJunior Well it depends. Actually if i want a fancy UI with adding, removing child items like in your scenario, I use a javascript framework like Angular.  But how you choose to render your UI is a different topic. Hard to say if you should use partial view or not. If the same model will be handled in multiple places the same way you can and maybe should use partial views. The json approach helps me populate the parent and ad/remove/edit child collections on the client side without posting back always. When I post,  I have full populated model validate it and save to db at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching I did not find anything suitable for my case, so I ended doing some code by myself. 
(I was not able to search to much, I believe there must be a better answer somewhere)

As I want to make them reusable i created them in a **partial view**.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{
        TempData["ParentToken"] = ViewBag.Token;
        Html.RenderAction("EstoqueOpcional", "Estoques");
    }
</div>
```

In my partial view I created an **AjaxForms**:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EstoqueOpcionalCreate", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "RegistroAdicionadoOpcional()", OnFailure = "ConectionFailed()", HttpMethod = "Post" })){
    @Html.Hidden("PageToken", (object)TempData["ParentToken"])
<!-- MY FIELDS -->
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar" class="btn btn-save" />
...
```

I have a page token in every page so I can create TempDatas using them without problem of the user opening multiple tabs of the same view. (ViewBag's isn't available because I'm not able to send anything back to the page).

Those are the scripts I created to control the display and stuff. (Most of them are still strongly typed as I still not refined my code yet)

```
<script>
function RegistroAdicionadoOpcional() {
    var newData = $("#dsopcional").val();

    var pass = true;
    $("#tableEstoqueOpcional .CheckData").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == newData)
            pass = false;
    });

    if (pass) {
        $("#tableEstoqueOpcional").append("<tr><td class=\"CheckData\">" + newData + "</td>" +
            "<td class=\"grid-cell temp-cell\" style=\"padding: 0px !important;\">" + "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return RemoveDataOpcional('" + newData + "');\">Remover</a>" + "</td></tr>");
        $("#dsopcional").val("");
        $("#dsopcional").focus();
    }
    else {
        Message("Error", "Esse valor já foi inserido.");
        $("#dsopcional").focus();
    }
}

function RemoveDataOpcional(value) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Estoques/RemoverOpcional",
        data: { opcional: value, PageToken: $("#PageToken").val() },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "True") {
                $("#tableEstoqueOpcional .CheckData").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).html() == value)
                        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
                });
            }
            else
                Message("Error", "Não foi possível remover o valor escolhido, tente atualizar a página.");
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            Message("Error", "Não foi possível remover o valor selecionado, se o erro persistir tente recarregar a página.");
        }
    });

}

@{
    var regs = "";
    if (TempData["EstoqueOpcional"] != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in (List<Models.EstoqueOpcional>)TempData["EstoqueOpcional"])
        {
            regs += "<tr><td class=\\\"CheckData\\\">" + item.DsOpcional + "</td>" +
                "<td class=\\\"grid-cell temp-cell\\\" style=\\\"padding: 0px !important;\\\">" + "<a href=\\\"#\\\" onclick=\\\"return RemoveDataOpcional('" + item.DsOpcional + "');\\\">Remover</a>" + "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    TempData["DisplayEstoque"] = regs;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(TempData["DisplayEstoque"].ToString()))";
    $("#tableEstoqueOpcional").append(text);
});
```

In my controller I created those methods to control the values in the TempData:

```
    public ActionResult EstoqueOpcional()
    {
        return PartialView(new EstoqueOpcional());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool EstoqueOpcionalCreate(EstoqueOpcional estoqueOpcional, string PageToken)
    {
        List<EstoqueOpcional> estoqueOpcionals = new List<EstoqueOpcional>();

        if (TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken] != null)
            estoqueOpcionals.AddRange((List<EstoqueOpcional>)TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken]);

        if (estoqueOpcionals.Where(x => x.DsOpcional == estoqueOpcional.DsOpcional).Count() == 0)
            estoqueOpcionals.Add(estoqueOpcional);

        TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken] = estoqueOpcionals;

        return true;
    }

    public bool RemoverOpcional(string opcional, string PageToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken] != null)
            {
                List<EstoqueOpcional> estoqueOpcionals = (List<EstoqueOpcional>)TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken];
                estoqueOpcionals.RemoveAll(x => x.DsOpcional == opcional);
                TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken] = estoqueOpcionals;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the update button button of my main model I have done like this:

```
            List<EstoqueOpcional> estoqueOpcionals = new List<EstoqueOpcional>();

            if (TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken] != null)
                estoqueOpcionals.AddRange((List<EstoqueOpcional>)TempData["EstoqueOpcional" + PageToken]);

            foreach (var estoqueopcional in estoqueOpcionals)
            {
                estoqueopcional.CdEstoque = estoque.CdEstoque;
                EstoqueOpcional estoqueopcionaltemp = db.EstoqueOpcional.Where(x => x.DsOpcional == estoqueopcional.DsOpcional).FirstOrDefault();

                if (estoqueopcionaltemp == null)
                    db.EstoqueOpcional.Add(estoqueopcional);
            }

            foreach (var item in db.EstoqueOpcional.Where(x => x.CdEstoque == estoque.CdEstoque).ToList()
                .Where(x => !estoqueOpcionals.Any(y => y.DsOpcional == x.DsOpcional)).ToList())
            {
                db.EstoqueOpcional.Remove(item);
            }
```

The create method it's very familiar with the update one.
I still believe there must be a easier way to do this, but this was suitable for me.

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWnm1.png)

Any advice or suggestion is welcome.
Thanks.